# With an nginx / gunicorn / Django setup, what logs the Bad Requests?

Tags: django, nginx, logging, gunicorn, bad-request

I'm following a teach yourself type book about how to set up a Python-based web thing.

I've just set up `gunicorn` so that it functions as a `systemd` service, rather than having to run it manually.

Previously, if a "Bad Request (400)" came in you would see something in the gunicorn server output. But now I don't know where, if at all, this is logged. Or which of the components involved does the logging.

From my searching I tried various things, like:

```
journalctl --unit=gunicorn | tail -n 300
```

... this produced nothing.

Someone also recommended /var/www/django for Django logs. But there is no such directory under /var/www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [gunicorn settings](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging) to specify where you would like to have it log

If these are not specified, it would log to your `stderr` for errors and `stdout` for access.